# OleDbCommandBuilder: GetUpdateCommand for Access query with parameters

Tags: .net, ms-access, vb6, oledb

I am trying to replicate a behavior from a VB6 app I'm migrating to .NET. 
I have an Access database with a several queries like this:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Id 
FROM Users
```

I can create a DbCommand and set the CommandText to "MyQuery" and CommandType to CommandType.StoredProcedure and the command is executed correctly.

To replicate the behavior in the VB6 application I try to create an update command from that command (I create a new dataAdapter and assign the created command as the SelectCommand).

Doing that, the creation of the Update Command (I use DbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand) fails with the message:

"Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any base table information."

As an alternative and since I am using Access as the Database, I changed the SelectCommand so the text is "Select * from MyQuery" and the type is "Text".

This works correctly and I can call DbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand succesfully.

The problem is that I also have some queries with parameters, like this:

```
PARAMETERS UserId Long;
SELECT users.firstname
FROM users
WHERE (((users.id) = UserId))
ORDER BY users.firstname;
```

The select is done succesfully when I set the SelectCommand text to "Select * from MyQueryWithParams" and the type to "Text" (I pass the parameters to the command).

However, when I call the DbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand it throws an exception:

"OleDbCommand.Prepare method requires parameters of type '14' have an explicitly set Precision and Scale."

And I don't see how to generate that update command automatically including the existing parameter.

I know I can just create a new stored procedure that takes care of the updates, however having 100's of scenarios in the application this adds a lot of work.

Is there any alternative to achieve this? Update values returned by a Query (SP) with a parameter?